# Adding popular posts by category in single posts?

Tags: popular-posts

I have been trying out several popular posts plugin but I can't seem to find the right one. I have a page where I want to insert popular posts (in between the textual content). I am looking for a plugin that can grab popular posts from categories and supports shortcode (as I want to insert popular posts only in a handful of pages). Any help is highly appreciated.

Edit: The page doesn't contain any sidebar, so I can only display posts within the content area.

Answer (score 1):

Does [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) do what you want?

Comment: I have tried this plugin already, but it will not display popular posts -- it will simply list posts from single or multiple categories. I was wondering if there is any way to display category posts by popularity using "List Category Posts?" Probably add something along the lines of orderby=popularity (doesn't work) or use any other similar function?